# plot mean of a continuous variable by a categorical variable and group by a factor

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'd think this would be fairly fundamental but can't find how to do it in any introductory texts that I have nor by googling. I want to  plot mean of a continuous variable by a categorical variable and then group by a factor. The continuous variable is 'cd' (blood cd4 protein), the categorical is year (1 - 10 years), the factor is failure = 0 or 1. My dataset is 'F3'

I've used aggregate to get the mean cd by year, but can't find how to group that by failure (0,1) for no and yes. Would prefer to use ggplot.

The plot I get from this:

```
ggplot(F3, aes(factor(year), mean(cd), color = factor(failure))) + 
geom_line()    + 
geom_point(size=2)
```

[image]

is a horizontal line or two lines overlaid, but indicating a group by failure in a legend. So, it's not plotting  the mean cd by year, just the overall mean. Please help.

**Data**:

```
F3 <- structure(list(year = structure(c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), cd = c(555L, 511L, 540L, 
596L, 553L, 142L, 173L, 271L, 163L, 108L, 61L), failure = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("year", 
"cd", "failure"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It would help if you'd make a more [reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Read what I linked, then edit the question.

Comment: d <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3Pep42z6")

Comment: str(F3) - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4K858KKV

Comment: Please read the link @Axeman provided again. Edit your question with a copy-paste of the data. SO is not only here to help you, but also future users and links can break.

Comment: Ok, I take it you're talking about the plot and code above. I'll take note of it for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Still unsure, but perhaps this is what you want to do? Using the larger dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

F4 <- F3 %>% group_by(year, failure) %>% summarize(cd = mean(cd))

ggplot(F4, aes(year, cd, color = failure, group = failure)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Including standard error of the mean:

```
F4 <- F3 %>% group_by(year, failure) %>% 
  summarize(mean.cd = mean(cd), se = sd(cd) / sqrt(n()))
F4$failure <- factor(F4$failure)

pos <- position_dodge(width = 0.2)

ggplot(F4, aes(year, mean.cd, color = failure, ymin = mean.cd - se, 
               ymax = mean.cd + se, group = failure)) +
  geom_point(position = pos) + geom_line(position = pos) + 
  geom_errorbar(position = pos, width = 0.2)
```

Note that some of the points have only one value, so you can't calculate the SEM or sd.

[image]

Comment: This ggplot2 code is what I did first. It's working here for a few cd values, but I need to mean cd for each year. There are over 3000 cd values in the full dataset. When all are plotted its an unreadable line chart with the cd values are sort of binned by year.

Comment: Your question gave different code. It is unclear to me what the problem is then.

Comment: Doesn't look like dplyr splice can select variables by another variable.

Comment: Can you access the pastebin? This is a 60-row slice http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SjH4u1Dq

Comment: I think I need to create a new variable that is tied wth each cd value to the year it belongs with.

Comment: Ok, I changed the answer.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. My first attempt to get SDs with expected 'sd = sd(cd)' is not working, but I'll work on it. Sorry about the data issue, I'll have to read up on it. Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: year [3]

   year failure       cd    sd
  (int)   (int)    (dbl) (dbl)
1     1       0 466.1103    NA

Comment: If you wanted sd's you should have put that in the question. You're making this a lot of work for others to figure out for you.

Comment: Sorry, guess I was thinking they go hand in hand, so doing the sd should be simple extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rCharts)
x1 <- xPlot(value ~ year, group = "failure", data = F3, type = "line-dotted")    
x1
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are froned upon on SO.

Comment: I think what I need is to create a new variable in the dataset that is the correct mean for cd  for each of the 10-year values (cdmean.y), then plot cdmean.y against year by the failure groups.

I can get the mean of cd with:

    F3.slice %>% group_by(year) %>%
     summarise (mean= mean(cd))
     cdmeanbyyear

How do I get a dataset like this:

year cd failure cdmean.y

Comment: I suppose you could make 10  sub-datasets for each year, then merge back into one? Is there an easier way?